# path for installation binaries for cabal

Tags: haskell, path, cabal, haskell-snap-framework

I am following the instructions for installing the snap framework for Haskell:

```
  http://janrain.com/blog/tutorial-building-a-sample-application-with-haskell-snap-postgresql-and-the-postgresql-simple-snaplet/
```

When executing

```
  snap init
```

I obtain `-bash: snap: command not found` (on Mac OSX), and I did open a new terminal window after installing snap. The binary is installed in

```
  /Users/<USER NAME>/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/snap-0.12.1/bin
```

and snap also works fine when `snap init` is prefaced with this path. However, this ticket
(for the windows cabal installer)

```
  http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/ticket/175
```

suggests that this should not happen. When cabal installs a new package, it should add the correct directories to the path environment. Running `set | grep "snap"` or `set | grep "cabal"` returns nothing. Any ideas on how to (automatically) add the correct directory to the PATH environment for future installations?

Comment: Normally Cabal installs executables in `~/.cabal/bin` (or `/usr/local/bin` for global installations), not in a package-specific directory. The ticket you are referring to talks about adding a single directory, roughly equivalent to `~/.cabal/bin`, to `%PATH%`. Under a UNIXy system you are supposed to do that yourself. What does your `~/.cabal/config` say under `install-dirs user` and `install-dirs global`?

Comment: Solved: Cabal creates links to binaries in $HOME/Library/Haskell/bin and adding `export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH"` into `.bash_profile` fixes the problem.

Comment: @n.m: Thank you for you quick reply. Sorry, I did not see your comment. ´~/.cabal/config´ indeed says: You may wish to place this on your PATH by adding the following line to your ~/.bash_profile: export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH". This solves the problem. (install-dirs is user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this was answered in the comments, but it would be nice to mark this question as answered.  This question is answered in the FAQ on the Snap website.

http://snapframework.com/faq#why-cant-i-install-snap